# How can I write a guard clause in a struct that returns more than one value

Tags: racket

I'm trying to create a struct in Racket as I've been teaching it to myself and I've been trying to run through different practice problems for it. Right now I'm trying to create a struct that has the following specifications:

> name: `grade`
>   fields:
>
> > `midterm` (must be integer and greater than 0
> >     `final` (must be integer and greater than 0)
> >     `course` (must be either symbol or false)

What I have written so far is this

```lisp
(struct grade (midterm final course)
  #:guard (λ (midterm final course name)
            (unless (and (integer? final) (> final 0))
              (error "not a valid final grade"))
            (unless (and (integer? midterm) (> midterm 0))
              (error "not a valid midterm grade"))
            (unless (or (symbol? course) (false? course))
              (error "not a valid course grade"))
            '(midterm final course)))
```

But it is unimplementable. I believe because the guard clause returns the list `'(midterm final course)`, but the other implementations I've tried, which involved the guard clause returning `(midterm final course)` and just `midterm final course` also did not work. What can I do to let this guard clause work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of the guard clause must be n [`values`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/values.html?q=values#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._values%29%29), one for each field of the struct. Note that this is distinct from a list. Assuming the rest of the logic is correct, you simply have to replace `'(midterm final course)` with `(values midterm final course)`. The complete result is below.

```
(struct grade (midterm final course)
  #:guard (λ (midterm final course name)
            (unless (and (integer? final) (> final 0))
              (error "not a valid final grade"))
            (unless (and (integer? midterm) (> midterm 0))
              (error "not a valid midterm grade"))
            (unless (or (symbol? course) (false? course))
              (error "not a valid course grade"))
            (values midterm final course)))
```

With this, I am able to do `(grade 100 100 'racket101)`, for example.

Comment: Thank you! I had no idea that `values` existed. This is perfect.